# Need to control look of textbox in DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF DataGrid with DataGridTextColumns next to DataGridTemplateColumns. The cells in the template columns contain a textbox which I disable when a checkbox is checked. My problem is the look/behavior of the cells in these two types of columns do not match when they are being edited. In my XAML below, I have set the background of my textbox in the template column to match the cell it is in, which is the way the textbox in a text column works. Now I need the textbox in the template column to turn white while being edited, as does the textbox in the text column.

Here is my XAML:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Rh" MinWidth="50" Binding="{Binding HorizontalResistivity, StringFormat=N2, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Rh min" MinWidth="50" >
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <TextBox x:Name="Rmin" Text="{Binding HorizontalResistivityMin, StringFormat=N2, Mode=TwoWay}"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0"
                     Background="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}}}"/>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=HorizontalResistivityIsFixed}" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="Rmin" Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have come reasonable close to the answer I need. I abandoned the DataGridTemplateColumn and reverted to the DataGridTextColumn I was using before it was determined that the data grid cell had to be disabled. Here is my XAML:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Rh min" MinWidth="50" Binding="{Binding HorizontalResistivityMin, StringFormat=N2, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HorizontalResistivityIsFixed}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="false"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
    <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Some explanation is in order. After I got the IsEnabled property correctly bound, I found that the TextBlock in the cell was no longer centered (it was aligned left), hence the ElementStyle section which aligned the TextBlock. Also during editing the cell contents would shift to the left. During editing the cell contents are a TextBox, so I have the EditingElementStyle section which aligns the TextBox.

That leave only one issue, while editing any TextBox in this column, the whole row expands in height, maybe 10%. This does not happen in any DataGridTextColumn that does not have the disabling feature. It also does not happen if I don't include the EditingElementStyle section. It seems that adding the DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle section messed with some defaults, and getting them all beck is a pain.